# How can I save both FK and IK animations in one .blend file?

Tags: animation

Here’s my problem: I exported a model from MakeHuman using the “game” rig. I imported the model into Blender, and made an animation using FK. From here, I am able to import my model and animation into Unity without issue.

Then, I added some IK bones/constraints to my model’s rig, and made another animation using IK. Now, I can't find a way to successfully import both animations to Unity. If I turn off the IK constraints, my FK animation works great but my IK animation is broken. If I leave them on, the reverse is true.

I've tried using visual keying, but it doesn't seem to apply to IK.

Is there some way I can bake the FK animation to always ignore the IK stuff? I would like to be able to get both of these animations into Unity without having to completely redo one of them (and further, I’d like to be able to work with IK or FK in the same model depending on what kind of animation I want to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but based on [this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html), you need to set up IK through a script so it works correctly.